# Swift - Cannot append Object to Array

Tags: arrays, swift, swiftui

I have created a New View in my App, but the Identifiable Object won't append to the Array.
I really don't know why its not appending...

Here is the Code:

```
struct FirstSettingsIdentifiables: Identifiable {
    var id: UUID = UUID()
    
    var name: String
    var icon: String
}
struct SettingsView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var settingItems: ContentModel
    
    @State var firstArr: [FirstSettingsIdentifiables] = []
    
    init() {
        createFirstList()
        print("Settings successfully initialized.")
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        
        return VStack {
            Text("Einstellungen")
                .font(.title)
            
            NavigationView {
                //Mitteilungen Liste
                List(firstArr) { x in
//                    ForEach(firstArr) { x in
    //                    VStack {
    //                        Image(systemName: x.icon)
                            Text("Das ist ein test")
    //                    }
//                    }
                }.navigationBarTitle("Mitteilungen")
            }
        }
    }
    
    func createFirstList() {
        
        let aText = "Mitteilungen"
        let aIcon = "info.circle.fill"
        let aObject = FirstSettingsIdentifiables(name: aText, icon: aIcon)
        
        firstArr.append(aObject)
        
        print(firstArr.count)
        
    }
    
    
}
```

The problem is probably in the `createFirstList()` Section. In this function, the Object `aObject` is full of data(This is working fine), but then the Object won't append to my `firstArr`. The count is always `0`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are changing the value of `firstArr` too early. Instead of calling `createFirstList()` in the `init`, remove that and instead add the following code onto the view body:

```
VStack {
    /* ... */
}
.onAppear(perform: createFirstList)
```

Alternatively, you could do the following:

```
init() {
    _firstArr = State(initialValue: getFirstList())
    print(firstArr.count)
    print("Settings successfully initialized.")
}

/* ... */

func getFirstList() -> [FirstSettingsIdentifiables] {
    let aText = "Mitteilungen"
    let aIcon = "info.circle.fill"
    let aObject = FirstSettingsIdentifiables(name: aText, icon: aIcon)
    return [aObject]
}
```

Comment: Well it works, BUT if I click on another View and then go back to this View, it executes the "createFirstList" function again. And the second Method cannot be used because I have more then 1 object to append in the future.

Comment: I added a Bool variable that sets to false after createFirstList gets executed and then don't executes again. But I don't think that this is the best way to solve it! Is there another way to do it?

Comment: @yama_HD I'm not sure what you mean. What is the reason for having your Boolean variable?

Comment: To Check if onAppear was already executed. Because its getting executed every time I open the view and then I have all variables twice

Comment: @yama_HD In that case, instead of `firstArr.append(aObject)`, do `firstArr = [aObject]`. That should fix your issue